# Functionality Scripts

Tags: scripting, task

Is it possible to write a program to do things you constantly do on a computer? For example, log into a torrent site and download a .torrent file then start it. Or go through folders and extract any RARed files? Or just do any monotonous thing you do daily on a computer. Just need a kick in the right direction.

Thanks,
-Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a rather vague question. It is possible to automate any task, but the applications you need to perform those tasks must provide an interface. Some GUI programs will accept command-line parameters so that you can automate their use in batch/script files but if the programs do not have such an interface, then you'll be looking at a clunky way of recording mouse movements. Great shout about PowerShell above but I understand the apps need to be coded to support that interface?

On unix-like systems such as linux, the philosophy is to have *at least* a command-line interface and *maybe* a GUI. You will be more likely to be able to script common tasks on that type of OS than a Windows one where the philosophy of user interface design is GUI-centric.

Answer (score 0):

Well

`for i in **/*.rar; do unrar e $i; done`
would unrar all rars, possibly

as for torrent thing, you can take perl, learn some http and use LWP library.

On windows, command line scripting is limited severely, unless you're using powershell which nobody really knows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many of these things are possible, given the right tools. On UNIX-like operating systems this sort of scripting is very common. On Windows somewhat less so.

Your question is very broad. If you have specific needs, then you should tell us which OS you're using, and which other programs you use. Then people may be able to give you proper directions.

If you're on e.g. Linux, have a look at [bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) [scripting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html).

Answer (score 0):

[PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is a pretty powerful scripting environment for that sort of thing, if we're talking Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).